# Extract a subset of data from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array that I need to extract a subset of data from where the value of the 2nd column is higher than a certain value.  What's the best way to do this?

E.g. given the array:

```
array1 = [[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]
```

I would want to extract all rows where the 2nd column was higher than 6, so I'd get:

```
[3, 7], [4, 8]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, even more simply:

```
a[a[:,1] > 6]
```

Output:

```
array([[3, 7], [4, 8]])
```

Where `a` is the array.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension:

```
array1 = [[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]

threshold = 6
print([elem for elem in array1 if elem[1] > threshold])
# [[3, 7], [4, 8]]
```

Or using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array(array1)
print(array1[array1[:,1] > 6])
# array([[3, 7], [4, 8]])
```

Comment: Does not really answer the question as it suggests the use of `numpy`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]])
# all elements where the second item it greater than 6:
print(a[np.where(a[:, 1] > 6)])
# output: [[3 7], [4 8]]
```